# mouse wheel event scroll c++ Visual Studio

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, events, c++-cli, mousewheel

I am making a program with windowForms  and I want to use the mouse wheel to do some things, like changing image  with the mouse wheel. I have been looking for some answers in the microsoft website but I couldn't understand it . Can anyone give me a example about mouse wheel event and what libraries I need to use.

Comment: I think you want `c++-cli` instead of `c++` if you are going to use `winforms`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was the library that i need to use

'#' using '<'System.dll'>'

'#' using '<'System.Windows.Forms.dll'>'

'#' using '<'System.Drawing.dll'>'

public ref class mainWindow : public System::Windows::Forms::Form

{

public:

```
    mainWindow(void)

    {

         InitializeComponent();

       //

        //TODO: Add the constructor code here

       //
    }
```

//inside InitializeComponent() i wrote:

```
       this->panel_album_info->MouseEnter += gcnew System::EventHandler(this,&mainWindow::panel_album_info_MouseEnter);



        this->panel_album_info->MouseWheel += gcnew System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventHandler(this, &mainWindow::panel_album_info_Mouse_Wheel);
```

code of each function

```
 private: System::Void panel_album_info_Mouse_Wheel(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^  e) {
//if (tenho_o_rato_no_panel_do_album_info == true)
//{
    int movimento = e->Delta;
    label1->Text = "teste";

    if (movimento == 120)

        numero_de_deslocações_do_album += 1;
    else if (movimento == -120)
        numero_de_deslocações_do_album -= 1;
    label1->Text = numero_de_deslocações_do_album.ToString();
//}
//else
    //return;

 }


private: System::Void panel_album_info_MouseEnter(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {


this->panel_album_info->Select(); //este tambem da mas nao sei qual é a diferença
//this->panel_album_info->Focus();

}
```

the code allows to scroll something without click it. the component that i want to scope was inside a panel object so i need to focus/select the panel object first.